# login to roundcube without logging in to cpanel

Tags: centos, cpanel, roundcube

I am trying to set up web mail for users on my server. I want them to be able to access RoundCube, but I have cPanel installed so the only way to access RoundCube is after logging in to cPanel. Since I do not want my users logging into cPanel? I could fake the session variables for a cPanel login, but I don't want my users to have access to anything in cPanel. Or should I try to install another webmail client? Will that even work?

Answer (score 0):

No need to install other webmail on your server, your client access webmail withour login cpanel with your domain name or server IP and webmail port no as below:

> yourdoaminname.com:2095

or

> serverIP:2095

simply enter email address and password to login.